# Eager Loading confusion. How to reduce queries

Tags: eloquent, eager-loading

I might be missing the point of eager loading but I'd like some clarification.

When I run the following query:

```
Capsule::connection()->enableQueryLog();

$result = Application::with([
    'country',
    'language',
])
->where('application.id', $applicationId)
->where('application.merchant_id', $merchantId)
->firstOrFail();

var_dump(Capsule::getQueryLog());
exit;
```

I get the output:

```
string(100) "select * from `application` where `application`.`id` = ? and `application`.`merchant_id` = ? limit 1"
string(53) "select * from `country` where `country`.`code` in (?)"
string(55) "select * from `language` where `language`.`code` in (?)"
```

I was expecting the sql generated to be a single query with a few joins.

I realise this isn't an n+1 issue. And maybe executing three queries here instead of one isn't actually a big deal in terms of performance. But I'd like to know how I can reduce this to one query anyway. I tried using `join` but that still resulted in three queries:

```
string(316) "select * from `application` inner join `country` on `country`.`code` = `application`.`country_id` inner join `currency` on `currency`.`code` = `application`.`currency_id` inner join `language` on `language`.`code` = `application`.`language_id` where `application`.`id` = ? and `application`.`merchant_id` = ? limit 1"
string(53) "select * from `country` where `country`.`code` in (?)"
string(55) "select * from `language` where `language`.`code` in (?)"
```

So my question is...

How can I get this down to a single query and be able to use the relationships aspect of Eloquent after to get the Country and Language data for an Application?

I'm not using the Laravel Framework if that makes any difference to your answer. I'm using Slim 3.

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading is supposed to work like this.

Merging all the queries using joins only works with one-to-one relationships. If you join on one-to-many or many-to-many relationships, you get **huge** results.

Even in cases like yours, multiple simple queries might be faster (or at least not 
slower) than one complex query. You would also have to add aliases for all columns to handle duplicate column names (`country.code`, `language.code` etc.).